# Why useState is not updated in setCnt?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I want updateState make a loop and add to cnt 1 after evry loop (this is a short example of what I'm tring to do, so it has to be just like this and not add 3 at the first time). but because setCnt is asynchronous it add just one for all the loop insted of 3.
any idia how to make it add every loop 3 synchronous?

```
const [cnt, setCnt] = useState(0)

const updateState = () => {
  for (var i = 1; i<3; i++){
  setCnt(cnt + 1)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('new state', cnt)
}, [cnt])

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={updateState}>Change state</button>
  </div>
)
}
```

thanks

Comment: Add the relevant code here in the question. Also looks like you're printing state on the line directly after changing it, that won't work. State changes are asynchronous

Comment: oh thanks, do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Solve what? William's answer below shows how to properly print it, are you having some other issue(s)? We need a better description of your specific problem and the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Since `setScore` function is asynchronous, and you can't get the updated state immediately after set state.
You need to get it in the useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(score)
}, [score])
```

Comment: thank you!, but where I update the score? (what should I write insted of setScore)

Comment: no need to update, you call `setScore` correctly, just you need to see the result in the useEffect

Comment: Just to be clear,  Should i add useEffect(() => {
  console.log(score)
}, [score]), and it should work (print the last update of setScore)?

Comment: refer to this. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you want to use the previous state value when setting state (in this case, previous value + 1) you need to pass a function to the set state call. The argument to that function is the previous state value. So this should do what you're looking for:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const updateCount = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      // Pass a function here
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Count:</h1>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <button onClick={updateCount}>Add 3 to count</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```